# My cropped image dosen't show in WordPress theme admin panel with manual image crop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mediaUploader;
    $("#upload-button").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (mediaUploader) {
            mediaUploader.open();
            return;
        }

        mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose ...',
            button: {
                text: 'banner'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

         mediaUploader.on("select", function () {
             attachment = mediaUploader.state().get("selection").first().toJSON();
             $("#pageBannerBackground").val(attachment.url);
         });
         mediaUploader.open();
    });
});
```

This is the PHP code I wrote. When I choose the photo and crop it, the output is not what I cropped and is the main photo.

```
    function mehrAmoz_page_banner_background() {
    $pageBannerBackground = esc_attr(get_option('pageBannerBackground'));
    echo "<h3 class=' btn btn--blue'>Background</h3>";
    echo "<div><input class='btn btn--small btn--beige' type='button' value='upload' id='upload-button'><input type='hidden' name='pageBannerBackground' id='pageBannerBackground' value='{$pageBannerBackground}'></div>";
    echo "<img class='homepageBanner' src='{$pageBannerBackground}'>";
}
```

Comment: i dont see any image cropping code

Comment: I do not see where your setting the attachment URL in the wp_options table